# Trying to add the day and time to a output file name (Python)

Tags: python, csv, xls

I'm trying to convert a xls file to csv and save it with a name `output`plus the date and time of today. The convertion works, but I'm having problems with the name of the file.
The desired ouput filename should be: `output day time.csv`, for example `output 2013-08-05 10:50:55.csv`.

This is my try. `name`prints me the stuff as I want, but when I put it on the `open()` funcion doesnt work.

```
 name = 'output '+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))+'.csv'
 archivo_csv = open(str(name), 'wb')
```

This is the entire function:

```
import xlrd
import csv

def xls_to_csv:
     print "Saving from xls to csv"
     wb = xlrd.open_workbook('example.xls')
     sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Page1')

     // This two lines are the ones that they are giving me problems
     name = 'output '+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))+'.csv'
     archivo_csv = open(str(name), 'wb')

     wr = csv.writer(archivo_csv, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
     for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
          wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))
     archivo_csv.close()
```

This is the error is showing:
`IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'output 2013-08-05 10:59:44.csv'`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'output 2013-08-05 10:59:44.csv'`

Comment: And your OS is? Perhaps you hit a limitation in what is allowed in the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using windows then it is the naming convention issue, in windows you can not keep
characters like  `: / \ > * ? " |` in the name..

try to keep the naming convention like

```
name = 'output '+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"))+'.csv'
```